# How to read conf.properties file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to read conf.properties file but but not by giving a hard coded path, so how can I fins it? I have use the below line but its written a null value but the path was correct.

InputStream inputStream = ReadPropertyFile.class.getResourceAsStream("configuration/conf.properties");

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have configuration folder in your project & that folder contains conf.properties
Use following in your function -

```
String projdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String propfilepath = projdir+"\\config\\"+"conf.properties";
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream(propfilepath ));

String value  = p.getProperty("test");
System.out.println(value); // It is returning me a value corresponding to key "test"
```